# CultureInfo conversions (C#)

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

Is it possible to get a specific CultureInfo by the TwoLetterISOLanguageName?
There is only a getter, not a setter... How would you do this. If possible without going through all cultures...

So not with:

```
// Get all available cultures on the current system.
CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);
foreach (var culture in cultures) {
   // Exclude custom cultures. 
   if ((culture.CultureTypes & CultureTypes.UserCustomCulture) == CultureTypes.UserCustomCulture) 
        continue;

   if (culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName == "<Whatever>"){
        //Do some stuff
        break;
   }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.twoletterisolanguagename.aspx

**SECOND:**

Is it possible to show the language as spoken in that language? 
Like 
     * Dutch -> Nederlands
     * German -> Deutsch
     * Spanish -> Español

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *constructor*, e.g.

```
  CultureInfo germanCulture = new CultureInfo("DE");
  CultureInfo russianCulture = new CultureInfo("RU");


  String germanNativeLanguage = germanCulture.NativeName; // <- Deutsch
  String russianNativeLanguage = russianCulture.NativeName; // <- русский


  String germanLanguage = germanCulture.EnglishName; // <- German
  String russianLanguage = russianCulture.EnglishName; // <- Russian
```

Comment: Another question... Is it possible to show the language as spoken in that language?

Comment: Like Dutch -> Nederlands,
     German -> Deutsch,
     Spanish -> Español

Comment: @RubenHerman Use `CultureInfo.NativeName` property to get that.

Comment: there are properties `Name` and `NativeName` or something like this afair.

Answer (score 2):

Use `CultureInfo(string)` constructor:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("<Whatever>");
```

It also works for cultures, that don't have two letter culture name

> If ISO 639-1 does not define a two-letter language code for a particular culture, the `TwoLetterISOLanguageName` property returns a string that consists of three or more letters.

e.g. for *Lower Sorbian (Germany)*:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("dsb");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the constructor, but I would prefer using the static method [`GetCultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yck8b540%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) because the docs explicitly say it returns a **cached** instance:

```
var ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("<TwoLetterISOLanguageName>");
```